# I want to call a variable outside the function in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

> i want to call name variable which is inside function
>   mycollection.fetch().Actually whenever i try to declare name variable
>   globally it fails to work.Thank you in advance.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    }

});

 var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "http://ec2-54-186-169-140.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/automation-poc-api/list",
    model: MyModel,
    parse : function(response){       
          return response;
        //api returns objects in the content attribute of response, need to override parse


    }
});

var myCollection = new MyCollection();
myCollection.fetch({
                success: function(col) {
                    // console.log(col.toJSON()[0].lists[0].name);
                    var name=col.toJSON()[0].lists[0].name;


                }

});
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say, **i want to call name variable** ?

Comment: var name which is inside success function.I want to access this variable aoutside the function @Cyclone

Comment: window.name is not working here

Comment: Are you trying to access it outside the `success` callback ?

Comment: Is this just the usual AJAX problem? You're trying to access `name` before the AJAX call has finished?

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring name locally inside the callback.

If you define name like

```
    var name;
```

before calling myCollection.fetch(), you can then put

```
    name=col.toJSON()[0].lists[0].name;
```

inside the success callback. Just be aware that the name value will not be updated until the asynchronous fetch has completed. If you tried this before and didn't see a value, it is probably because the response had not occurred and the name value was not yet initialized.